# Add Array to ArrayList in one go

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, arraylist, mscorlib

**Background:**

I'm trying to populate an `ArrayList` object from any given array of values.

To populate these objects you can either use `.Add` method or the `.AddRange` method, however either way it seems that you need to iterate over your array to populate the `ArrayList`. And apparently, to make use of `.AddRange` we need to make use of the `Queue` object.

***Code:***

*Example of the `.Add` method:*

```
Sub Test1()

Dim ArrList As Object: Set ArrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

With ArrList
    For Each ArrItem In Array("A", "B", "C")
        If Not .contains(ArrItem) Then .Add ArrItem
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

*Example of the `.AddRange` method:*

```
Sub Test2()

Dim ArrList As Object: Set ArrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim Q As Object: Set Q = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")

With Q
    For Each ArrItem In Array("A", "B", "C")
        If Not .contains(ArrItem) Then .Enqueue ArrItem
    Next
End With

ArrList.AddRange Q

End Sub
```

***Question:***

As you can see, I wonder what the purpose is of the `.AddRange` method if we can't assign an array directly. We still had to iterate and `.Enqueue` them.

So what can be done to assign an array at once? Obviously, the following will error (5) out:

```
ArrList.AddRange Array("A", "B", "C")
```

---

Btw, for early binding, add the `mscorlib.dll` reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ArrayList` is a .NET object and the [`AddRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.addrange) method expects a parameter of type `ICollection`. Now, a VBA array is not an `ICollection` object (i.e., it doesn't implement the .NET's `ICollection` interface), therefore, the call to the method fails.

The reason a `Queue` object works is that it does implement ICollection. Any other `ICollection` object would work too. For example, if you have another `ArrayList`, you can pass that to the `AddRange` method and it would work just fine. Try this, for example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ArrList1 As Object: Set ArrList1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim ArrList2 As Object: Set ArrList2 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    ArrList1.Add "A"
    ArrList1.Add "B"
    ArrList1.Add "C"

    ArrList2.AddRange ArrList1
End Sub
```

**So, the bottom line is:** I guess you're out of luck using a VBA array to pass to the `ArrayList.AddRange()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I take it that in this regard there is simply not really any use for the `AddRange` method within vba.

Comment: @JvdV Well, it could be useful if, for example, you have a function that returns an `ArrayList` or a `Queue` object and you want to append its items to an existing `ArrayList`. Other than that, no I don't think so. In .NET, however, it can be more useful because you can directly add an array (or any object that implements `ICollection`). Although `ArrayList` is actually obsolete in the .NET world now since better alternatives already exist.

Comment: One last thing, remember that you can always write your own function which does what you thought `AddRange` would do.

Comment: Been a few weeks, and not so much a new question but more so an observation, that the `.ToArray` method works unlike most other methods. I find that so confusing. Just wanted to let you know that reading from an array in one go is not possible, but reading into an array (or worksheet range) is....strange.